# Completely reinstall everything on Mac mini

Tags: mac-mini

My Mac mini behaves in strange ways.  Certain applications open randomly, downloads just don’t download sometimes, for a while I could not empty the trash, etc.
I want to cleanly erase everything that my computer is including the kernel, Hardware, SMC Recovery firmware and everything else and just put back fresh operational replacements.  I am not looking to buy a new computer (like other questions here said to do) I do not know which one or couple of things is corrupted but I want to just get rid of everything and start over without bricking my computer.  Any ideas?

Comment: What model year is the Mac? What version of macOS do you have installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart the machine, while holding <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>. The option key gives you the latest supported version of macOS rather than what it shipped with. Then follow the prompts to reinstall a new macOS.

As long as you have a backup of your needed documents and settings I would also erase the drive with disk utility within the process of reinstalling, that will ensure nothing is left over from a potentially damaged OS install.

Comment: Thanks, @Steve Chambers. That's indeed improved.

Comment: Thanks! But will that also reinstall the kernel? A friend of mine said that based on the behavior the kernel might be corrupted

Comment: Yes, the kernel will be replaced. It's part of the operating system.